# Jquery deferred.done doesn't recognize result type of function

Tags: jquery-deferred

I created the code below which generates the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`. I think I understand what's happening here, `def()` isn't a deferred until the timeout expires and the `.done` tries to run straight away, but what I don't understand is if this doesn't work, why do deferreds work at all? How does `.done` **ever** know that the code in front is a promise/deferred given that it may not have resolved yet? Please **explain** syntax that will make it work, because this is doing my head in.

To put it bluntly I wish that .done would just shut up and wait like it's meant to (I understand that it would have to be a method of all objects and wait until they've resolved even if it's not to a deferred, but if you've typed `.done` why wouldn't you want that?). Or does it work that way, but I just don't know how to use it properly?

Please don't just refer me to an existing guide/post on jquery deferred unless it **explicitly** resolves my confusion.

Thanks.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y9x19h1h/4/)

```
function def() {
    d = new $.Deferred;
    setTimeout(function(){
        d.resolve();
        return d;
    },1000)
}
def().done(function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the promise value from `def()` itself, not from the `setTimeout()`.

```
function def() {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){
        d.resolve();
    },1000)
    return d;
}
def().done(function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

Returning a value from `setTimeout()` doesn't do anything.  `def()` has long since finished executing (and returning nothing) and the return value from `setTimeout()` just goes back into part of the system runtime that calls timer callbacks and is ignored.

I also made a couple other corrections:

1. Declared `d` as a local variable (not an implicit global) by putting `var` in front of its declaration.
2. Changed the creation of the deferred to `$.Deferred()`.  While, I think the `new` construction might work, that isn't how jQuery has documented its usage.

Comment: Would you believe that as I decided to fire up the computer to see if there was a response I realised the mistake I'd made? So often it's stepping away from it which brings clarity. Thanks for the confirmation and the additional corrections. It's embarrassing to have to ask questions like this. I'd debug it myself, but I can only get so much information with only (front end and) console  output working and that only at javascript level. I don't know how anyone works this way, but at least it's free and I'm in no position to splash cash for a commercial development environment.

Comment: @SteveC - you can't use one of the good debuggers?  I use the Chrome debugger all the time for browser development and node-inspector for node.js development.  Maybe not all the bells and whistles of some development environments, but they are real debuggers are completely free and save me tons of time.

Comment: I use Aptana. It only seems to work with Firefox (– internal server, whatever that means). FirePHP doesn't work. Trying to run my app in Debug produces a 'Socket connection error'. I don't understand how Aptana can be so popular when it seems half-finished. It's like they just threw it out there and we're meant to guess how to make it do anything beyond being a glorified text editor.